# Does not display toaster if first before redirecting to another page, in Angular4?

Tags: angular

I am using Angular4. I have used the [toaster package](https://github.com/PointInside/ng2-toastr).

Now my requirement is: if delete the user then redirect the another component and between show the toaster on delete. So how is it possible? Redirect another page and show toaster. Please share some code.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`this.router` [navigate](https://angular.io/api/router/Router#navigate) is a promise it will return true if navigation completed. You can use it like this:

```
  this.router.navigate(['/heroes']).then(() => {
    this.toasts.show('message');
  })
```

If you need just to show after you deleted just use it like this:

```
this.service.delete(user).toPromise().then(() => {
    this.toasts.show('message');
    this.router.navigate(['/heroes']);
 })
```

Comment: This is work fine but does not cancel automatically because this code in the first component:- public toastr : ToastsManager, public vRef: ViewContainerRef. So how to automatically disable after some time?

Comment: You can set the time of toast so it will disable itself after time. 
this.toastr.sucess('This toast will dismiss in 10 seconds.', null, {toastLife: 10000});

Comment: I have set all options in app module file like this:- export class CustomOption extends ToastOptions {
  animate = 'fade in';
  toastLife = 10000
  positionClass = 'toast-top-center';
}

Comment: Have you done this line:  
providers: [ 
    {provide: ToastOptions, useClass: CustomOption},

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154215/discussion-between-harleen-kaur-arora-and-alexkhymenko).

Answer (score -1):

```
this.router.navigate(['URL']).then(() => {
                    this.toastr.success('Message', 'Success!!', { showCloseButton: true });
                });
```